# Origin of "direct variation"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

A definition from "College Algebra, 4ed." by Beecher, Penna, and Bittinger:

> If a situation gives rise to a linear function $f(x) = kx$, or $y = kx$, where $k$ is a positive constant, we say that we have direct variation, or that $y$ varies directly as $x$, or that $y$ is directly proportional to $x$. The number $k$ is called the variation constant, or the constant of proportionality.

I never heard of "direct variation" until I started teaching from this book, and there are about ten times more results on Google for "directly proportional" than "direct variation". So I have to assume that using the word "variation" is a modern invention, or at least unpopular.

Where and when did this "direct variation" terminology originate? And why use "$y$ varies directly as $x$" instead of the seemingly more grammatical "$y$ varies directly with $x$"?